# Is Swift incompatible with pre-ARC Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, swift

I'm starting to add Swift files to a very large, legacy Objective-C project that doesn't use ARC.

When I compile the project, I get warnings for every property emitted in the `ProjectName-Swift.h` bridge header:

- No 'assign', 'retain', or 'copy' attribute is specified - 'assign' is assumed
- Default property attribute 'assign' not appropriate for non-GC object

It seems like Swift is emitting ARC-based Objective-C code.

Is this a limitation/bug in this particular release of Swift, or is Swift designed to work only with ARC code?

Comment: I really have no idea why you're not using ARC yet. I get that it's legacy code, but legacy code should be updated...

Comment: the era of "pre-ARC" called `MRC`, maybe it is good to know what you are using.

Comment: @LordZsolt To avoid unnecessarily introducing memory management bugs in a large codebase that's been well-tested under the pre-ARC memory management regime.

Comment: @holex I think it's better known as `MRR`.

Comment: @LordZsolt Not everyone likes ARC. For one, ARC syntax is cumbersome, and the fact that a strong `self` pointer is implicit in blocks (leading to retain cycles) is even worse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can mix ARC and non-ARC code. All ARC-compiled code does is manage its memory automatically to the user. You should enable ARC for your project and then disable ARC for individual files using `-fno-objc-arc` or enable ARC for just Swift files using `-fobjc-arc` (this may not be necessary as the compiler may automatically be adding it). Swift code is eventually compiled to use the same Objective C runtime, and ARC calls inserted by the compiler are the same as in Objective C. After compilation, ARC and non-ARC code behave the same.

Comment: Everything you write is correct but has nothing to do with the question. The problem is not "after" but "during compile time" where the compiler is reading header files and the header file that Swift generates always assumes ARC, so if you use that header file in non-ARC classes, the objects will behave correctly after compilation, no problem, but the compiler will throw warnings as for non-ARC files that import this header, the header is not correct and I'm afraid that's just the way it is, I couldn't find any solution either.

Comment: What does "not correct" mean? Do you mean ARC-intended modifiers, such as `weak` and `strong`?

Comment: If a property has no storage attribute, it is `assign` in non-ARC but it is `retain`/`strong` in ARC, so if you want to use the same header file in both, ARC and non-ARC Obj-C files, you must always use an explicit storage attribute, otherwise the compiler will once think that this is an `assign` property and once that this a `strong` property, but in reality, it can only be either one, so one assumption will always be false. Swift doesn't set any attribute for `strong` vars, so Swift assumes that the header file is only used in ARC code.

Comment: Using it in non-ARC code will still work, despite the warning, since, as you correctly pointed out, once the code has been compiled, it doesn't matter anymore. It's the Swift code that decides what is the "truth" and not the header file and if the property is `strong`, than it is `strong`, even if the header file makes the compiler believe it is not.

Comment: @Mecki Just checked in a Swift generated header, and I see a different result: `@property (nonatomic, strong) UILocalNotification * _Nullable localNotification;` This is how a Swift property is exposed in the `-Swift.h` file.

Comment: Yes, sometimes Swift will do that but apparently not always. E.g. from one of my projects `@property (nonatomic) NSError * _Nullable lastError;` - the Swift Code is `var lastError: Error? = nil`. Maybe as it is optional? Maybe as it is initialized in place? Maybe as it is `Error` being mapped to `NSError`? Or maybe it is `Apple Swift version 3.1 (swiftlang-802.0.36.2 clang-802.0.35)` (Xcode 8.3beta3)? I really don't know

Comment: Definitely looks like a bug in the generator. Suggest filing a bug report at https://bugs.swift.org/.

Answer (score 1):

The header file that Swift generates for Obj-C seems to assume ARC is being used in your Obj-C code. Depending on your Xcode version and build settings, you may have a warning enabled that warns you whenever a property is implicitly an `assign`-property, which is only the case in non-ARC code as in ARC code, properties are implicitly `strong` (which is exactly the same as `retain` in non-ARC code). With that warning enabled, you will get that warning every time you import the generated header into a .m file that is non-ARC and Swift has not set a storage attribute for that property.

But that warning does not mean that the compiled code won't work correctly later on. Despite the fact that the compiler believes this property is only `assign`, it will for sure not be `assign` as Swift properties cannot even be `assign`, they can be `strong` or the can be `weak` (`weak` is not the same as `assign`! `weak`-properties become `nil` when the object dies, `assign`-properties become dangling pointers and still point to the address where the object used to live). The worst thing that this can cause, despite the warning, is an incorrect static code analyzer result as the analyzer may also warn you how this `assign`-property can break your code and again, the analyzer is wrong as the property simple is not `assign` in reality.

To fix that, the only thing that was required is to never rely on a property being anything by default and always correctly tagging all properties as `strong`, which also works in non-ARC code (`strong` and `retain` are just synonyms for the compiler, it treats both exactly the same, so both can be used in non-ARC code). The funny thing is quite often that is exactly what Swift does. I have tons of `strong` properties in my generated header but apparently there are situations where Swift won't do it (maybe that's actually a Swift bug).

And easy work-a-round for that problem is to just disable the warning when importing the generated header, which can be done as follows:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-property-no-attribute"
#import "xxx-Swift.h"
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Just pack that into another header file, e.g. `My-xxx-Swift.h` and then only import `My-xxx-Swift.h` everywhere in your code.

I wouldn't disable it for the whole project (e.g. in the Xcode build settings) as usually this warning is quite meaningful and can help to prevent terrible bugs when mixing ARC and non-ARC code, as maybe a property doesn't really have the storage attribute you think it has and thus when mixing ARC and non-ARC, you are strongly advised to never rely on implicit attributes and always make the storage explicit.

Answer (score 0):

> When I compile the project, I get warnings for every property emitted in the ProjectName-Swift.h bridge header

I was able to get rid of the warnings once I converted all of my files to ARC. (Not using `-fno-objc-arc`)